# Let $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ Lebesgue integrable. Prove $\int{f(x)dx}=\int{f(x+t)}dx$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ Lebesgue integrable. Prove

$$\int{f(x)dx}=\int{f(x+t)}dx$$

**My attempt:**
Suppose $f\geq 0$, Let $\varphi$  an increasing sequence $0\leq\varphi_{n}\leq f$ of simple functions such that $\varphi_{n}\uparrow f$ and we have by Monotone Convergence Theorem(Beppo-Levy) that

$$\int f=\lim_{n}\int\varphi_{n}$$

here i'm stuck. can someone help me?

Comment: Is that integral over the whole of $\Bbb R$? Like $\int_{\Bbb R}{f(x)dx}=\int_{\Bbb R}{f(x+t)}dx$

Comment: yes is over $\mathbb{R}$ @Mirko

Comment: Hint: Use the three/four steps in the construction of Lebesgue integral. First consider characteristic functions and simple functions.